# typist.js while lines expanding the page scrolling bottom

Tags: jquery, css

In my first page I have a booting sequence for which I used [typist.js](http://albburtsev.github.io/jquery.typist/) plugin. But my lines are expanding after filling up the page, but the problem is scrollbar is standing top of it instead of following the sequence. For that I tried adding:

```
.on('type.typist', function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, $(document).height());
});
```

Top code on the bottom code. But it didn't work even the lines aren't show up on the page.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.typist').typist({ speed: 150 })
                .typistPause(1)
                .typistAdd('[!]:./action.SYSTEM.BOOT\n')
                .typistPause(1)
                .typistAdd('\n')
                .typistPause(1)
                .typistAdd('[!]:./initiating.DEBUG.MODE\n')
});
```

So what could be the solution? Thanks for any help.

Here is my last update: http://jsfiddle.net/kodbilenadam/eb48gybv/

Comment: Try moving the browser's scroll bar ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893282/how-can-i-move-the-web-browsers-scrollbar-and-style-it-css)) or use anchors inside of your text and jump to these anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code and how the [typist "Dialog" demo](http://albburtsev.github.io/jquery.typist/src/html/dialog.html) does it in the `printPhrase()` function. After a new dialog line was added, it calls [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to move the document's `body` element down:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, 'slow');
```